# Undefined variable error that shouldn't be a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I've made a piece of code in jquery that assigns a href attribute to a variable. Here's that code:

```
$('#reactions' + i).attr('href', 'javascript:comments ('+entry.url+','+i+');');
```

This should assign a call to the javascript function comments. Now I want to use that call on a jquery mobile button, like this:

```
document.write('<a href="#" id="reactions' + i + '" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right">Reactions</a>');
```

But doing this gives me a in FF and Chrome. This is the error from FF±

> Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: i_heart_chaos_ihc_after_dark_independence_day_through_a_bullhornthis_is_what
>   Error thrown at line 1, column 0 in javascript:comments (i_heart_chaos_ihc_after_dark_independence_day_through_a_bullhornthis_is_what,1);:
>       comments (i_heart_chaos_ihc_after_dark_independence_day_through_a_bullhornthis_is_what,1);

In this, `i_heart_chaos_ihc_after_dark_independence_day_through_a_bullhornthis_is_what` is the value of `entry.url`.

I'm just not getting why this error appears, as far as I know, everything should work.
I know that there are questions looking similar to mine, but I couldn't figure out the answer. If you want to see the whole source, it's [here](http://scoutline.3owl.com/test/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround entry.url with quotes:

```
    $('#reactions' + i).attr('href', 'javascript:comments ("'+entry.url+'",'+i+');');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix the issue is to do it the "jQuery way". Instead of adding a href attribute that executes JavaScript, add a click event:

```
$('#reactions' + i).click( function() {
    comments( entry.url, i );
});
```

Similarly don't use `document.write()` but add elements to the document using jQuery functions.